# Inserting factors into columns of a data frame using rep()

Tags: r

I am trying to add factors to each observation in a data frame. Particularly, I  have a data frame called test with 7 columns and 100 rows. I initialize it like this:

```
test<-as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=7,nrow=100))
> names(test1)
[1] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" "V5" "V6" "V7"
```

I want to insert the factors "Employed", "Unemployed", "Out of labor" force" that are repeated 65 ,20, 15 times respectively into the V1 column. My attempt with "Employed":

```
test$V1<-rep("Employed", time=65)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "V1", value = c("Employed", "Employed",  : 
replacement has 65 rows, data has 100
```

As you can see I get an error. I am looking for a quick unsophisticated solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to make your rep() vector the same length as the number of rows in your data.frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
test$V1 <- c(rep("Employed", time=65), rep("Unemployed", 20), rep("Out of Labor", 15))
```

Comment: This needs to be wrapped with `as.factor` to create the factor levels.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `times` argument in `rep` to tell how many times to repeat each value. Then, you need `factor` to actually create a factor. Otherwise it will just be a vector of strings.

```
> test$V1 <- factor( rep(c("Employed", "Unemployed", "Out of labor"),
                         times=c(65,20,15)) )
> table(test$V1)
Employed Out of labor   Unemployed 
      65           15           20
```

You can see the difference between using `factor` and not with this code:

```
> rep(c("A","B","C"), 2)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "A" "B" "C"
> factor(rep(c("A","B","C"), 2))
[1] A B C A B C
Levels: A B C
```

Note that in the first case we don't have a factor but a vector of strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `replicate` instead of `rep`. Then `as.factor` to create the factors and convert the `class` from character to factor.

```
> f <- c("Employed", "Unemployed", "Out of labor force")
> test$V1 <- unlist(mapply(replicate, c(65, 20, 15), as.factor(f)))
```

Comment: This very useful for a big number of factors. Thanks.

Comment: Any time.  Glad I could help.